# How to add custom data to hystrix-metrics-event-stream?

Tags: hystrix

I would like to add some more JSON fields to the [hystrix-metrics-event-stream](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/tree/master/hystrix-contrib/hystrix-metrics-event-stream) for each HystrixCommand.

What is the proposed way to do it?

Thanks for any hint